# Alternative to the Everything search engine?

Tags: windows-xp, file-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the fastest desktop search tools you’ve used on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows)

I love the speed of [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), but am frustrated by its lack of sorting options. Is there an alternative which has comparable speed but more bells an whistles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [**Locate32**](http://www.locate32.net/).

> Locate32 is software which can be used
>   to find files from your harddrives and
>   other locations. It works like
>   updatedb and locate commands in Unix
>   based systems. In other words, it uses
>   databases to store information about
>   directory structures and uses these
>   databases in searches. The use of
>   these databases provides very fast
>   searching speed. The software includes
>   a dialog based application as well as
>   console programs which can be used to
>   both update and access databases.

Comment: I use locate32 when I want to search contents inside a file as Everything doesn't allow that